# VBScript: Use Shape property in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, controls, shapes

I wrote a VBScript to Export data in a .xlsx file. A Dropdown control should filter the data. The following code shows you my adding method:

```
sub AddDropDownElement
    FirstSheet.DropDowns.Add(0, 0, 100, 15).Name = "SheetFilter"

    with FirstSheet.Shapes("SheetFilter")
        .IncrementLeft 20.4
        .IncrementTop 34.2

        .Placement = xlFreeFloating
        .PrintObject = False
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .DropDownLines = 12
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
end Sub
```

FirstSheet is a worksheet of a "Excel.Application".

To execute the Increment-methods works perfectly. The properties are unknown in VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your properties are not direct members of a `Shape` object: some belong to `ControlFormat` and one to `DropDown`

```
Sub AddDropDownElement()
    Const DD_NM = "SheetFilter"

    FirstSheet.DropDowns.Add(0, 0, 100, 15).Name = DD_NM

    With FirstSheet.Shapes(DD_NM)
        .IncrementLeft 20.4
        .IncrementTop 34.2
        .Placement = xlFreeFloating
        With .ControlFormat
            .PrintObject = False
            .ListFillRange = ""
            .LinkedCell = ""
            .DropDownLines = 12
        End With
    End With
    FirstSheet.DropDowns(DD_NM).Display3DShading = True

End Sub
```

Tested in Excel 2013

Comment: in principle you are right but e.g. the property "Placement" is not known.

Comment: Did you add a reference to Excel, or are you using late binding?  If late binding, did you define `xlFreeFloating`?

Comment: the fail message was wrong. As you said the `xlFreeFloating` was not defined.